# Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary with values of same class together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a DataFrame with two columns. I want to convert this DataFrame to a python dictionary. I want the elements of first column be keys and the element of other column be values.

```
   item_cat_id  item_id
0            0       12
1            2       11
2            1       13
3            3       20
4            1       22
5            1       19
6            2       15
7            0       25
```

I want my output as dictionary:

`{'0': [12,25], '1': [13,22,19], '2': [11,15],  '3' : [20]}`

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby('item_cat_id')['item_id'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Sample Data:

```
    Animal  Number_legs
0   fox         4
1   Kangaroo    2
2   deer        4
3   spider      8
4   fox         7
```

Code:

```
df.groupby('Animal')['Number_legs'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Result:

```
{'Kangaroo': [2], 'deer': [4], 'fox': [4, 7], 'spider': [8]}
```

Comment: but what if I have

Comment: item_cat_id  item_id
            0       12
            2       11
            1       22
            3       20
            1       22
            1       19
            2       15
            0       12

Comment: what if I have item_id same for two rows with same item_cat_id

Comment: @Amit not a problem. I replaced Kangaroo in the above example with fox - 4 and here is the result: {'deer': [4], 'fox': [4, 4, 7], 'spider': [8]} But you don't want duplicate entries that's a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
df.groupby('item_cat_id').item_id.agg(lambda x: list(x)).to_dict()
```

result:

```
{0: [12, 25], 1: [13, 22, 19], 2: [11, 15], 3: [20]}
```